# Unable to JOIN the same table twice based on two conditions

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm using MySQL with PHP. Here is my query on which I'm getting the error.

```
$query = 
"SELECT days.day, count(myDataTable.appId) as countf, count(myDataTable.appId) as counts
            FROM
              (
               select curdate() as day
               union select curdate() - interval 1 day
               union select curdate() - interval 2 day
               union select curdate() - interval 3 day
               union select curdate() - interval 4 day
               union select curdate() - interval 5 day
               union select curdate() - interval 6 day
               union select curdate() - interval 7 day
               union select curdate() - interval 8 day
               union select curdate() - interval 9 day
               ) days
              left join myDataTable as n1
              on days.day = n1.date AND n1.appId = '$id' AND n1.status = 'ERROR'
              group by days.day
              left join myDataTable as n2
              on days.day = n2.date AND n2.appId = '$id' AND n2.status = 'SUCCESS'
              group by days.day";
```

The error log is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near  'left join myDataTable on days.day = myDataTable.date AND myDataTable.appId ' at line 17
```

Comment: Remove `AS` in table aliases: `left join myDataTable as n1 on days.day =`, make it `left join myDataTable n1 on days.day =`

Comment: You should simplify your query until your mistake becomes obvious (I'm only guessing but I don't think you can have two `group by`'s in the same level query). Also,  use prepared statements instead of embedding parameters into your SQL string

Comment: You have two group bys in your query remove the first one that is hanging out, oddly, in your FROM clause. Also, removing the AS will have no affect. That `AS` is optional in MySQL for Aliases, but it certainly won't hurt.

Comment: removing first `GROUP BY` makes it to show `'Unknown column 'myDataTable.appId' in 'field list'`

Comment: @TodorSimeonov MySQL allows `as` in table aliases.

Comment: Right. That's another error. `myDataTable` isn't an alias of any of your tables in your `FROM` clause. Change that to either `n1` or `n2` depending on which `appID` you are counting.

Comment: @PraveshAgrawal When you give a table an alias, you have to use the alias, you can't use the table name any more.

Comment: Alright @Barmar, I'm already using it as `n1.appId` & `n2.appId`

Comment: But you have `count(myDataTable.appId)`. You can't use the table name because you assigned aliases to the table.

Comment: I don't understand the point of counting the same column twice

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to properly indent your SQL so you can spot the mistakes. Indenting by the main keywords (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY) will help you spot them quickly:

```
SELECT 
    days.day, 
    count (myDataTable.appId) as countf, 
    count(myDataTable.appId) as counts
FROM
  (
     select curdate() as day
       union select curdate() - interval 1 day
       union select curdate() - interval 2 day
       union select curdate() - interval 3 day
       union select curdate() - interval 4 day
       union select curdate() - interval 5 day
       union select curdate() - interval 6 day
       union select curdate() - interval 7 day
       union select curdate() - interval 8 day
       union select curdate() - interval 9 day
   ) days
  left join myDataTable as n1
       on days.day = n1.date AND n1.appId = '$id' AND n1.status = 'ERROR'
group by
  days.day
  left join myDataTable as n2
       on days.day = n2.date AND n2.appId = '$id' AND n2.status = 'SUCCESS'
group by
  days.day
```

You can see that you have two GROUP BY's which won't work. Furthermore you have a `LEFT JOIN` hanging out in the first `GROUP BY` clause, which doesn't work either. Removing that first `GROUP BY` will get you closer:

```
SELECT 
    days.day, 
    count (myDataTable.appId) as countf, 
    count(myDataTable.appId) as counts
FROM
  (
     select curdate() as day
       union select curdate() - interval 1 day
       union select curdate() - interval 2 day
       union select curdate() - interval 3 day
       union select curdate() - interval 4 day
       union select curdate() - interval 5 day
       union select curdate() - interval 6 day
       union select curdate() - interval 7 day
       union select curdate() - interval 8 day
       union select curdate() - interval 9 day
   ) days
  left join myDataTable as n1
       on days.day = n1.date AND n1.appId = '$id' AND n1.status = 'ERROR'
  left join myDataTable as n2
       on days.day = n2.date AND n2.appId = '$id' AND n2.status = 'SUCCESS'
group by
  days.day
```

No you have a proper FROM clause. This is the first part that your Database looks at so it knows from where it is getting it's data and how it joins together. Your table aliases are set here and then used EVERYWHERE else in the query. Which leads you to the second problem.

You reference `myDataTable` up in your SELECT clause, but by the time the database is looking at your `SELECT` `myDataTable` isn't in context. The aliases `n1` and `n2` are though, so change these to reference your table aliases:

```
SELECT 
    days.day, 
    count (n1.appId) as countf, 
    count(n2.appId) as counts
FROM
  (
     select curdate() as day
       union select curdate() - interval 1 day
       union select curdate() - interval 2 day
       union select curdate() - interval 3 day
       union select curdate() - interval 4 day
       union select curdate() - interval 5 day
       union select curdate() - interval 6 day
       union select curdate() - interval 7 day
       union select curdate() - interval 8 day
       union select curdate() - interval 9 day
   ) days
  left join myDataTable as n1
       on days.day = n1.date AND n1.appId = '$id' AND n1.status = 'ERROR'
  left join myDataTable as n2
       on days.day = n2.date AND n2.appId = '$id' AND n2.status = 'SUCCESS'
group by
  days.day
```

Lastly, instead of joining your `myDataTable` in twice for each status, you can use a `CASE` statement in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    days.day,
    SUM(CASE WHEN n1.status = 'ERROR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countf,
    SUM(CASE WHEN n1.status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as counts    
FROM
  (
     select curdate() as day
       union select curdate() - interval 1 day
       union select curdate() - interval 2 day
       union select curdate() - interval 3 day
       union select curdate() - interval 4 day
       union select curdate() - interval 5 day
       union select curdate() - interval 6 day
       union select curdate() - interval 7 day
       union select curdate() - interval 8 day
       union select curdate() - interval 9 day
   ) days
  left join myDataTable as n1
       on days.day = n1.date AND n1.appId = '$id'  
group by
  days.day
```